# SQL запрос выдает ошибку CASE types interval and integer cannot be matched

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
with week_profit as(
    select date_trunc('week', date), sum(profit_ln) as profit_ln from trader_profit_log
    group by date_trunc('week', date)
), 
    trader_week AS (
      SELECT case min(profit_ln) = '-inf'::float WHEN TRUE then -1 else ((exp(min(profit_ln)) - 1)/avg(exp(profit_ln) - 1)) * INTERVAL '1 week' end max_dd_restore
      FROM week_profit HAVING min(profit_ln) < 0
  ) 
UPDATE trader SET max_dd_restore = trader_week.max_dd_restore FROM trader_week
WHERE trader_week.max_dd_restore = trader.id;
```

Ошибка типа:

```
ERROR: CASE types interval and integer cannot be matched
```

Comment: У вас `then` возвращает int, а `else` возвращает Interval, приведите их к одному типу.

Answer (score 1):

У вас в case в одном случае возвращается -1 (integer), в другом - интервал. Приведите к одному типу.